# MS Excel 365: localhost urls open in native browsers instead of pop-up dialogue

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

I am using dialogueAsync to open some html pages for my custom application. When the urls are hosted on a remote system e.g. https://so-and-so.com/etc.html it opens up as a pop-up which is like a dialogue box. 
The moment I change the url to localhost i.e.to a webpage deployed locally in my system - http://localhost:8080/etc.html, the html opens up in my default browser which as a new tab.

It is very painful to implement waiting / progress  dialogues on my local, as dialogue does not close automatically - dialogWindow.close() never works.

Is there any way around?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part: in the manifest that you are sideloading, what is the original base URL?  It might be that you need to add your localhost to the AddDomains list: 
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomain.

For the `dialogWindow.close()`, I suggest you open a separate question, to ensure that the question/suggestion doesn't get lost in being mixed in with your first question.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with domain. I have already added localhost in the list of AppDomains  : <AppDomain>http://localhost:8080</AppDomain>. Moreover, I observed that the difference of http and https in url is creating this problem. Any reason why http based urls are not supported to be opened in dialogues?